# How to do conditional rendering using JWT in my backend development project which is using MVC architecture?

Tags: express, authentication, model-view-controller, jwt

I want to access total points of a user. It works well in the postman. But for front end, I need to know who is currently log in to show user*points. I need to get user*_id that jwt stores in local storage.

For context this is what my folder structure looks like, [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBvF5.png)

jwtMiddleware.js from src/middlewares/

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// REQUIRE DOTENV MODULE
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
require("dotenv").config();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// REQUIRE JWT MODULE
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SET JWT CONFIGURATION
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const secretKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY;
const tokenDuration = process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN;
const tokenAlgorithm = process.env.JWT_ALGORITHM;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MIDDLEWARE FUNCTION FOR GENERATING JWT TOKEN
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module.exports.generateToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const payload = {
    userId: res.locals.userId,
    timestamp: new Date(),
  };

  const options = {
    algorithm: tokenAlgorithm,
    expiresIn: tokenDuration,
  };

  const callback = (err, token) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error jwt:", err);
      res.status(500).json(err);
    } else {
      res.locals.token = token;
      next();
    }
  };

  const token = jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, options, callback);
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MIDDLEWARE FUNCTION FOR SENDING JWT TOKEN
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module.exports.sendToken = (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: res.locals.message,
    token: res.locals.token,
  });
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MIDDLEWARE FUNCTION FOR VERIFYING JWT TOKEN
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module.exports.verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "No token provided" });
  }

  const token = authHeader.substring(7);

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "No token provided" });
  }

  const callback = (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid token" });
    }

    res.locals.userId = decoded.userId;
    res.locals.tokenTimestamp = decoded.timestamp;

    next();
  };

  jwt.verify(token, secretKey, callback);
};
```

mainRoutes from src/routes

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const usersRoute = require("./usersRoutes");
const tasksRoute = require("./tasksRoutes");
const taskProgressRoute = require("./taskProgressRoutes");
const userPointsRoute = require("./userPointsRoutes");
const cardsRoute = require("./cardsRoutes");
const playersRoute = require("./playersRoutes");
const locationsRoute = require("./locationsRoutes");
const decksRoute = require("./decksRoutes");
const battlesRoute = require("./battlesRoutes");

// const exampleController = require('../controllers/exampleController');
const jwtMiddleware = require("../middlewares/jwtMiddleware");
const bcryptMiddleware = require("../middlewares/bcryptMiddleware");
const userController = require("../controllers/usersController");

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DEFINE ROUTES
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

router.post(
  "/register",
  userController.checkUsernameOrEmailExist,
  bcryptMiddleware.hashPassword,
  userController.register,
  jwtMiddleware.generateToken,
  jwtMiddleware.sendToken
);

router.post(
  "/login",
  userController.login,
  bcryptMiddleware.comparePassword,
  jwtMiddleware.generateToken,
  jwtMiddleware.sendToken
);



router.use("/users", usersRoute);
router.use("/tasks", tasksRoute);
router.use("/task_progress", taskProgressRoute);
router.use("/user_points", userPointsRoute);
router.use("/cards", cardsRoute);
router.use("/players", playersRoute);
router.use("/locations", locationsRoute);
router.use("/", decksRoute);
router.use("/battles", battlesRoute);

module.exports = router;
```

this is the loginUser.js from public/js that school provided like a template

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const callback = (responseStatus, responseData) => {
    console.log("responseStatus:", responseStatus);
    console.log("responseData:", responseData);
    if (responseStatus == 200) {
      // Check if login was successful
      if (responseData.token) {
        // Store the token in local storage
        localStorage.setItem("token", responseData.token);
        // Redirect or perform further actions for logged-in user
        window.location.href = "choosePlayer.html";
      }
    } else {
      warningCard.classList.remove("d-none");
      warningText.innerText = responseData.message;
    }
  };

  const loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm");

  const warningCard = document.getElementById("warningCard");
  const warningText = document.getElementById("warningText");

  loginForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    console.log("loginForm.addEventListener");
    event.preventDefault();

    const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    const data = {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    };
    // Perform login request
    fetchMethod(currentUrl + "/api/login", callback, "POST", data);

    // Reset the form fields
    loginForm.reset();
  });
});
```

queryCmds.js from public/

```
//=====================================================================================
// FETCH METHOD
// This function uses the fetch API to make a request to the server.
//=====================================================================================
function fetchMethod(url, callback, method = "GET", data = null, token = null) {
  console.log("fetchMethod: ", url, method, data, token);

  const headers = {};

  if (data) {
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
  }

  if (token) {
    headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
  }

  let options = {
    method: method.toUpperCase(),
    headers: headers,
  };

  if (method.toUpperCase() !== "GET" && data !== null) {
    options.body = JSON.stringify(data);
  }

  fetch(url, options)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status == 204) {
        callback(response.status, {});
      } else {
        response
          .json()
          .then((responseData) => callback(response.status, responseData));
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(`Error from ${method} ${url}:`, error));
}
```

I tried getting token from local storage and decoding it but I cannot access node modules from public to decode jwt token.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Retrieve the token from local storage
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  // Check if the token is present
  if (token) {
    // Decode the token to access the user ID
    const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token);

    // Access the user ID from the decoded token
    const userId = decodedToken.userId;

    // Now you can use the userId as needed
    console.log("User ID from JWT:", userId);
  } else {
    // Handle the case where the token is not present
    console.error("Token not found");
  }
});
```